# Xcode 9 FBSDKLoginManager crash involving FBSDKInternalUtility

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I've Installed FacebookSDKs iOS v4.28 in to Xcode 9, and added a custom Facebook Login button using FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate. When the button is pressed, it runs this function:

```
func handleFacebookLogin() {

    FBSDKLoginManager().logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email", "public_profile"], from: self { (result, err) in

         ... code ...

    }
}
```

When this function is called, it leads to an uncaught exception of type NSException. Here is the _11_dispatch_once [inlined] code:

```
Grouphack`+[FBSDKInternalUtility isFacebookAppInstalled]:
    0x1002e2868 <+0>:  stp    x20, x19, [sp, #-0x20]!
    0x1002e286c <+4>:  stp    x29, x30, [sp, #0x10]
    0x1002e2870 <+8>:  add    x29, sp, #0x10            ; =0x10 
    0x1002e2874 <+12>: mov    x19, x0
    0x1002e2878 <+16>: nop    
    0x1002e287c <+20>: ldr    x8, #0x5ffc4              ; isFacebookAppInstalled.onceToken
    0x1002e2880 <+24>: cmn    x8, #0x1                  ; =0x1 
    0x1002e2884 <+28>: b.ne   0x1002e28a8               ; <+64> [inlined] _dispatch_once at FBSDKInternalUtility.m:493
    0x1002e2888 <+32>: nop    
    0x1002e288c <+36>: ldr    x1, #0x59fc4              ; "_canOpenURLScheme:"
    0x1002e2890 <+40>: adr    x2, #0x49908              ; @"fbauth2"
    0x1002e2894 <+44>: nop    
    0x1002e2898 <+48>: mov    x0, x19
    0x1002e289c <+52>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp, #0x10]
    0x1002e28a0 <+56>: ldp    x20, x19, [sp], #0x20
    0x1002e28a4 <+60>: b      0x10030c56c               ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
    0x1002e28a8 <+64>: adr    x0, #0x5ff98              ; isFacebookAppInstalled.onceToken
    0x1002e28ac <+68>: nop    
    0x1002e28b0 <+72>: adr    x1, #0x42790              ; __block_literal_global.286
    0x1002e28b4 <+76>: nop    
    0x1002e28b8 <+80>: bl     0x10030c434               ; symbol stub for: dispatch_once
    0x1002e28bc <+84>: b      0x1002e2888               ; <+32> at FBSDKInternalUtility.m:496
```

No other information is given in the console.
What is the cause of this exception?